# shared-preference cannot use with intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I got a problem in my new android project. I cannot use the shared-preference with the intent starting. While i run my project it gets a force close and showing null-pointer exception in log-cat. Can anyone suggest anything to solve to this issue ? And here is my class

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    String a,b;
    Context cntxt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nextlayout);

        TextView et3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        SharedPreferences prefs = cntxt.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
        a =  prefs.getString("KEY_FIRST","");

            et3.setText(a);

            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent t = new Intent(cntxt,Kl_Activity.class);
                startActivity(t);
                }
            // and get whatever type user account id is

        });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please post logcat error ?

Comment: Think we found the problem guys?

Comment: @agen451 Write NextActivity.this instead of cntxt, it will solve your problem.

Comment: I must say @agen451 you been very lucky that you got 5 correct answer in 5 mins..

Comment: Roll a five-sided die and pick one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is at this line

`SharedPreferences prefs = cntxt.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);`

because you didnt init cntxt..

so just replace

```
cntxt =this;
SharedPreferences prefs = cntxt.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
```

or remove cntxt from line.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
```

Comment: what should i assign for that ?

Comment: only **this** like as cntxt =this;

Answer (score 3):

this line is the problem

```
SharedPreferences prefs = cntxt.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
```

where you init `cntxt` ?

use like this

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You never set `cntxt` to anything. No worries though, because you don't need it. `Activity` is a `Context`. You can just call `getSharedPreferences(...)` within the class.

Answer (score 2):

**I found the problem in your code . You use cntxt without initialize it . So before accessing it initialize it.**

```
setContentView(R.layout.nextlayout);
cntxt = this;
```

### Or

Do not use cntxt .

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    String a,b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nextlayout);

        TextView et3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
        a =  prefs.getString("KEY_FIRST","");

            et3.setText(a);

            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent t = new Intent(this,Kl_Activity.class);
                startActivity(t);
                }
            // and get whatever type user account id is

        });
}
}
```